# How to add additional condition to this validation formula?

Tags: formula, case, validation-rule

Hi we have a formula to make a field mandatory based on this condition.

To this condition we need to add another condition like if the Recordtype is =.

Please find the formula we have wrote.

IF(UPPER( Credit_Invoice_1__c ) = "CM", FALSE, ISPICKVAL(Refund_Method__c, ""))

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would better be served as a straight Boolean expression rather than using IF:

```
AND(
  NOT(UPPER(Credit_Invoice_1__c) = "CM")),
  ISPICKVAL(Refund_Method__c, ""),
  $RecordType.Name = "SOME_RECORD_TYPE"
)
```